# How do I search GoToWebinar List of registrants using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I've got the below class in C#. I call the GoToWebinar API function to get the list of registrants for a webinar. It returns a List

```
public class ResponseWebinarAttendees
{
    // Will only be using the joinUrl but need to have all the data points, just in case
    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    public string type { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "timeZone")]
    public string timeZone { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "status")]
    public string status { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "firstName")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "lastName")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "email")]
    public string email { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "registrantKey")]
    public string registrantKey { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "registrationDate")]
    public string registrationDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "attendeeId")]
    public string attendeeId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "joinUrl")]
    public string joinUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Can I search the List for registrants with a particular email address using LINQ?

Comment: If you have an IEnumerable or IList of ResponseWebinarAttendees it's pretty straightforward, just call myList.Where(x => x.email == "desiredemail")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a collection, you can inline any number of OR | AND clauses inside of your `.Where()` method.

```
var filteredResult = attendees.Where(x => x.email == "email@email.com" || 
                                          x.email == "email2@email.com");
```